how do i setup gunicorn conf in amazon EC2 ubuntu?
I am trying to deploy my django project on EC2 ubuntu instance:
i have configured conf/gunicorn_config.py:
command = "/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn"
pythonpath = "/home/ubuntu/my_project"
bind = "13.232.32.207:8000"
workers = 1

then i run :
gunicorn -c conf/gunicorn_config.py myproject.wsgi

it gives error:
[2024-05-25 14:38:27 +0000] [8359] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
[2024-05-25 14:38:27 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('13.232.32.207', 8000)
[2024-05-25 14:38:27 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2024-05-25 14:38:28 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('13.232.32.207', 8000)
[2024-05-25 14:38:28 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2024-05-25 14:38:29 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('13.232.32.207', 8000)
[2024-05-25 14:38:29 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2024-05-25 14:38:30 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('13.232.32.207', 8000)
[2024-05-25 14:38:30 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2024-05-25 14:38:31 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('13.232.32.207', 8000)
[2024-05-25 14:38:31 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2024-05-25 14:38:32 +0000] [8359] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('13.232.32.207', 8000)


EC2 uses a 1:1 NAT.  You either need to bind to the private IP address that corresponds to your public IP, or just bind to 0.0.0.0 if you don't have specific needs to bind to one of several public IP addresses.

If you have nginx in front of this app you can bind to 127.0.0.1 and proxy_pass to 127.0.0.1:8000
